# Настройка PyCharm Python

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Приветствую. Как убрать вот это подсвечивание?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пишет. `no data sources are configured to run this sql.` Просто надо отключить это желтое бесячее подсвечивание

Answer (score 0):

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections` 
Inspections можно вводить в строке поиска, чтобы было проще искать и далее выключаете все что не нужно.

Comment: Я знаю дирректорию, что надо убирать?

Comment: Инспекцию **SQL | No data sources configured**. Можно также через **Alt+Enter | Configure data source | Disable inspection**.